# width of datagrid column is not as declared

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, grid, actualwidth

I have a `DataGrid` with some columns set. In addition, there's `Grid`, whose column width I want to set (not bind) to the total of 3 `DataGrid`'s columns width. What I'm trying to do is practically some "super headers" to the `DataGrid` columns.

the `DataGrid` columns are `CheckBoxColumn`s with headers that are wider than the content of the cells themselves. When I query the `dataGrid.Columns[0].ActualWidth` I get (I think) the width of the checkboxes, and not the REAL width of the columns, which is the width of the header.

Please help !

using C# / WPF, visual studio 2013

All in code, please, no XAML

Comment: I did understand what are you looking to accomplish exactly!  correct me if i am wrong : you have a Grid on Top of a DataGrid, and You want to link between the Grid's columns width and the dataGrid's Columns Width, Right ?

Comment: Indeed, but want to make some grid columns as wide as several datagrid columns each.
By the way, all in code, please, no XAML

Comment: I've made a small test application and it works right. Post your code if you want additional help.

Comment: @Giangregorio, I am afraid this would be a bit complicated. The development system is on another network (a classified one) with no communication between them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using

```
column.MinWidth = column.ActualWidth;
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star;
```